# grails how to set full text index

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I can't find info on this quite simple question. I've a simple domain class like this

```
Class VehicleRequest{
    LocalDateTime startTime
    LocalDateTime endTime
    Status status
    String destination
    User reqUser  
}
```

In my service i'd like to query vehicle requests that have similar destination (based on text matching). I m using MySQL Innodb 5.5. If possible I dont want to add plugin just for one field. Is there any work-around?
Thanks
NoonYuki

Comment: i think you need to use MySQl MyISAM storage engine.

Comment: i dont know how to edit my own question. >.<. basically i want to search vehicle requests that has similar destination, start time, end time.

Comment: @iswanto san thanks for quick reply. I can't change to MyISAM storage as i need transaction support. Is there any other option?